# Вылеает приложение при попытке применить тему (Android)

Tags: android, android-themes

В моём приложении тема применяется в `onCreate()` до выполнения `setContentView(...)`. При попытке применения темы (то есть при запуске) приложение падает с ошибкой. Это всё происходит на Android 4.2.2 (для андроид 5+ у меня предусмотрена другая тема, с ней проблем нет). Что может быть не так?
Тема:

```
    <style name="BookTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/brown100</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BookActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="BookActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/brownPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Код:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    try {
        if (pref.getInt(PREF_THEME, R.style.BasicTheme)==R.style.BookTheme){
            setTheme(R.style.BookTheme);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {Notificator.showPrompt(e.getMessage());}
  ...
}
```

Ошибка:

```
24.11.17 15:19
Version: build 3 (1)
Thread[main,5,main]
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Message: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad/ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
Stacktrace:
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Exception: android.view.InflateException
Message: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
Stacktrace:
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2851)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2915)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:296)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
    ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity.initEditor(MainActivity.java:66)
    ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Message: null
Stacktrace:
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2851)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2915)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:296)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
    ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity.initEditor(MainActivity.java:66)
    ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Message: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070000 a=3 r=0x7f070000}
Stacktrace:
    android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1967)
    android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3338)
    android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:436)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
    android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
    com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:52)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2851)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2915)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:296)
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
    ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity.initEditor(MainActivity.java:66)
    ua.leonidius.rtlnotepad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Может от `AppCompatActivity` наследуетесь?

Comment: Нет, у меня вообще в приложении нету appcompat библиотеки

Comment: Тогда весь стектрейс что-ли покажите.

Comment: Добавил в текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам решил проблему. Дело было в том, что цвета, которые я использую в этой теме, были объявлены в файле styles.xml из папки values-v21. Я создал в папке values файл colors.xml, переместил цвета туда и всё заработало.